# Facebook Login - Why for some users, the permissions are not showing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

My problem is happenning during Facebook Login process. Sometimes, when a user connect through our app and try to give us permissions to their facebook pages, not all permissions that we asked for in the "Facebook Login" scope are showed.

Expected result : During login, show all permissions indicated in the scope Facebook Login

Result : Not all permissions are showed.

Thank you by advance,

Regards.

Comment: Are we talking about users that have a role in the app, or "general public"? If the latter, have all permission that require it, been approved by Facebook in your app review? Have those users perhaps been asked for those permissions before already - but declined to grant them?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CBroe !

I'm talking about "general public". The mindfuck is the next, the process is working for somes users and for other no. So I think the permissions are ok, but I'm maybe wrong.

They cannot decline the permissions because the permissions are not showing.